# Cannot use protocol to define common initializers

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to create a generic class that is able to convert models to their associated view models. Unfortunately the compiler does not allow it and fails with the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Model' (generic parameter of generic class 'Store') to expected argument type 'ViewModel.Model' (associated type of protocol 'StoreViewModel')
```

I'm using the following simplified code:

```swift
protocol StoreViewModel {
    associatedtype Model

    init(model: Model)
}

class Store<Model, ViewModel: StoreViewModel> {
    var models = [Model]()
    var results = [ViewModel]()

    func update() {
        results = models.map {
            ViewModel(model: $0)
            // Cannot convert value of type 'Model' (generic parameter of generic class 'Store') to expected argument type 'ViewModel.Model' (associated type of protocol 'StoreViewModel')
        }
    }
}

class Foo: NSManagedObject {}

class FooViewModel: StoreViewModel {
    var model: Foo
    required init(model: Foo) {
        self.model = model
    }
}

let store = Store<Foo, FooViewModel>()
```

I've already read about type erasure, but I'm wondering of there is no simpler solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is, your current code allows things like:

```
let store = Store<Int, FooViewModel>()
```

Clearly that makes no sense, but your code allows it because there is no constraint on `Model`. `Model` can be anything, can't it?

Let's put a constraint on:

```
class Store<Model, ViewModel: StoreViewModel> where Model == ViewModel.Model {
```

Now we see that there is no point of having two generic parameters! Why use `Model`, when we can just use `ViewModel.Model`?

```
class Store<ViewModel: StoreViewModel> {
    var models = [ViewModel.Model]()
```

or, if you hate long type names, use a `typealias`:

```
typealias Model = ViewModel.Model
var models = [Model]()
```